# How to build a single form powershell gui application

Tags: forms, powershell, user-interface, dialog, modal-dialog

I would like to know how to do a gui powershell application that allows user to navigate through forms without using modal dialog boxes but only the parent dialog.
For example, I have a form **A** that has buttons and textboxes.
I want to display another form lets say **B** when the user clicks on a buttton but without opening a child dialog box.

Actually, I succeed to go to the form **A** to the form **B**.

What I really want to do is going to a third form lets say **C** from the form **B** by clicking on a button as well.

It's seems that I'm missing something and unfortunately I cant find someone who shows how to do it.

Here is a sample of the code.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 300, 300 )
$button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button.Text = "gotoB"
$button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point( 200, 200 )
$button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 70, 25 )
$button.Add_Click( {
        $form.Controls.Remove( $button )
        $form.Update()            
        LoadScreen2 -Form $form
    })
$form.Controls.Add( $button )
$form.ShowDialog()

function LoadScreen2 () {
    [cmdletbinding()] param 
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
        [System.Windows.Forms.Form]$Form
    )
    $bbutton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $bbutton.Text = "gotoC"
    $bbutton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point( 200, 200 )
    $bbutton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 70, 25 )        
    $bbutton.Add_Click({
            $Form.Controls.Remove($bbutton)                
            LoadScreen3 -Form $Form
    })       
    $Form.Controls.Add($bbutton)
    $Form.Update()
}

function LoadScreen3 () {
    [cmdletbinding()] param 
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
        [System.Windows.Forms.Form]$Form
    )        
    $cbutton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $cbutton.Text = "goNowhere"
    $cbutton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point( 200, 200 )
    $cbutton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 70, 25 )
    $cbutton.Add_Click({})
    $Form.Controls.Add($cbutton)
    $Form.Update()              
}
```

Comment: i think what you want is tabs. this ... TabControl Control - Windows Forms .NET Framework | Microsoft Docs — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/tabcontrol-control-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: Thank you for replying Lee Dailey. Actually, I dont want tabs. I intentionally simplified my code for the purpose of understanding.

Comment: This is not a PowerShell code issue. It's a UX/UI design question. So, really it's off-topic. I've done this a lot in the past in VBA/VB/VB.Net/C#, etc. You could have just used containers(GroupBox), that hold different form elements, and then leverage SendToBack/BringToFront or visibility (hide/show) actions. Yet, again, this not a PowerShell issue, as you'd have this same problem using any UX/UI programming language as a design goal.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found how to do this.
I had to put the following line just before calling the **LoadScreen3** function:

```
$Form.Controls.Clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending from my comment. So, just using group boxes (vs say your obversion to the tabbed interface option), yet ultimately the same thing.

All you'd need to do is add whatever from the elements you choose to each of the individual group boxes, they would all be contained in the individual group box.

Again, this is all UX/UI code and would work regardless of the programming language involved for other reasons. Your baseline UX/UI should just work. The code behind is for other data, string, interop needs.

```
$SingleFormUXUI = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Form

[System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox]$grpMainPage    = $null
[System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox]$grpDataPage    = $null
[System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox]$grpDetailsPage = $null

[System.Windows.Forms.Label]$lblMainPage       = $null
[System.Windows.Forms.Label]$lblFormPage       = $null

[System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox]$cbxSelectPage  = $null


function InitializeComponent
{
    $grpMainPage    = (New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox)
    $grpDataPage    = (New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox)
    $grpDetailsPage = (New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox)
    $cbxSelectPage  = (New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox)
    $lblMainPage    = (New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Label)
    $lblFormPage    = (New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Label)

    $grpMainPage.SuspendLayout()

    $SingleFormUXUI.SuspendLayout()
    #
    #grpMainPage
    #
    $grpMainPage.Controls.Add($lblMainPage)
    $grpMainPage.Location = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]11,[System.Int32]12))
    $grpMainPage.Name     = [System.String]'grpMainPage'
    $grpMainPage.Size     = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]587,[System.Int32]325))
    $grpMainPage.TabIndex = [System.Int32]1
    $grpMainPage.TabStop  = $false
    $grpMainPage.Text     = [System.String]'MainPage'
    $grpMainPage.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $true
    $grpMainPage.Visible  = $false
    #
    #grpDataPage
    #
    $grpDataPage.Location = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]12,[System.Int32]12))
    $grpDataPage.Name     = [System.String]'grpDataPage'
    $grpDataPage.Size     = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]586,[System.Int32]325))
    $grpDataPage.TabIndex = [System.Int32]2
    $grpDataPage.TabStop  = $false
    $grpDataPage.Text     = [System.String]'DataPage'
    $grpDataPage.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $true
    $grpDataPage.Visible  = $false
    #
    #grpDetailsPage
    #
    $grpDetailsPage.Location = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]12,[System.Int32]12))
    $grpDetailsPage.Name     = [System.String]'grpDetailsPage'
    $grpDetailsPage.Size     = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]586,[System.Int32]325))
    $grpDetailsPage.TabIndex = [System.Int32]3
    $grpDetailsPage.TabStop  = $false
    $grpDetailsPage.Text     = [System.String]'DetailsPage'
    $grpDetailsPage.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $true
    $grpDetailsPage.Visible  = $false
    #
    #cbxSelectPage
    #
    $cbxSelectPage.FormattingEnabled = $true
    $cbxSelectPage.Items.AddRange(
        [System.Object[]]@([System.String]'Main Page',
        [System.String]'Data Page',
        [System.String]'DetailsPage Page')
    )

    $cbxSelectPage.Location          = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]444,[System.Int32]338))
    $cbxSelectPage.Name              = [System.String]'cbxSelectPage'
    $cbxSelectPage.Size              = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]153,[System.Int32]21))
    $cbxSelectPage.TabIndex          = [System.Int32]4
    #
    #lblMainPage
    #
    $lblMainPage.Location = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]7,[System.Int32]17))
    $lblMainPage.Name     = [System.String]'lblMainPage'
    $lblMainPage.Size     = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]295,[System.Int32]19))
    $lblMainPage.TabIndex = [System.Int32]0
    $lblMainPage.Text     = [System.String]'Use the dropdown box to select a page to work with.'
    $lblMainPage.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $true

    $cbxSelectPage.Add_TextChanged(
    {
        switch($cbxSelectPage.Text)
        {
            'Main Page'    
            {
                $grpMainPage.Visible    = $true
                $grpMainPage.BackColor  = [System.Drawing.ColorTranslator]::FromHtml("#4a90e2")
                $grpDataPage.Visible    = $false
                $grpDetailsPage.Visible = $false
            }
            'Data Page'    
            {
                $grpDataPage.Visible    = $true
                $grpDataPage.BackColor  = [System.Drawing.ColorTranslator]::FromHtml("#50e3c2")
                $grpMainPage.Visible    = $false
                $grpDetailsPage.Visible = $false
            }
            'DetailsPage Page' 
            {
                $grpDetailsPage.Visible   = $true
                $grpDetailsPage.BackColor = [System.Drawing.ColorTranslator]::FromHtml("#9b9b9b")
                $grpMainPage.Visible      = $false
                $grpDataPage.Visible      = $false
            }
        }
    })

    #
    #SingleFormUXUI
    #
    $SingleFormUXUI.ClientSize = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]599,[System.Int32]375))
    #
    #lblFormPage
    #
    $lblFormPage.Location                   = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]10,[System.Int32]338))
    $lblFormPage.Name                       = [System.String]'lblFormPage'
    $lblFormPage.Size                       = (New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Size -ArgumentList @([System.Int32]333,[System.Int32]19))
    $lblFormPage.TabIndex                   = [System.Int32]0
    $lblFormPage.Text                       = [System.String]'Welcome to my UX/UI. Use the dropdown box to select a page.'
    $lblFormPage.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $true
    #
    $SingleFormUXUI.Controls.AddRange(
        @(
            $lblFormPage,
            $grpMainPage,
            $grpDataPage,
            $grpDetailsPage,
            $cbxSelectPage
        )
    )
    $SingleFormUXUI.Text = [System.String]'Single from MDI UX/UI'

    $grpMainPage.ResumeLayout($false)
    $SingleFormUXUI.ResumeLayout($false)

    Add-Member -InputObject $SingleFormUXUI -Name grpMainPage -Value $grpMainPage -MemberType NoteProperty
    Add-Member -InputObject $SingleFormUXUI -Name lblMainPage -Value $lblMainPage -MemberType NoteProperty
    Add-Member -InputObject $SingleFormUXUI -Name grpDataPage -Value $grpDataPage -MemberType NoteProperty
    Add-Member -InputObject $SingleFormUXUI -Name grpDetailsPage -Value $grpDetailsPage -MemberType NoteProperty
    Add-Member -InputObject $SingleFormUXUI -Name cbxSelectPage -Value $cbxSelectPage -MemberType NoteProperty

    $SingleFormUXUI.ShowDialog()
}
. InitializeComponent
```